# sceneStorage is not storing data and I have to use AppStorage for it

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to persist the selected tab information in `@SceneStorage`.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @SceneStorage("selectedTab") var selectedTab: String = "list"
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            Text("1")
                .tabItem(Text("1")).tag("1")
            Text("2")
                .tabItem(Text("2")).tag("2")
            Text("3")
                .tabItem(Text("3")).tag("3")
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I use `@AppStorage` it's working fine. Why is that?
I have been using Xcode 15.

Comment: Maybe a typo, have you tried using `@SceneStorage("selectedTab") ...`

Comment: What sort of persistence are you expecting? SceneStorage doesn’t persist on app closing.

Comment: @RoyRodney, what do you mean by app closing? Obviously scenStorage is the preferred method in this case (Tab selection) and I don't know why it's not working here.

Comment: Tested your code (with the fixed typo that you had) on real ios17 devices, and all works well for me.
 Note, I replaced `.tabItem(...)` with `.tabItem{Text("1")}.tag("1")` etc...
Could not make it work in MacCatalyst.